# Fetching data from multiple MS Forms Workbooks to one main Workbook automatically

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a requirement in which I have different forms filled in Microsoft Forms, which are being saved as different workbooks.

Now I want to combine all these files into one single workbook so that they can be analyse or a dashboard be created out of this. Is there a way that I can do that easily, which means anytime anyone fills out a feedback in any of the forms it should populate my main Workbook automatically?

I tried the referencing method i.e

```
=IF(ISBLANK('https://MyOneDriveLink/Documents/[Feedback1.xlsx]Sheet1'!$D$2:$D$6), " ",('https://MyOneDriveLink/Documents/[Feedback1.xlsx]Sheet1'!$D$2:$D$6))
```

Using the above it does populate the current entries in my Main Workbook, but it does not repopulate when someone fills out a new response.

I want to do this with multiple workbooks, i.e. when ever a response comes in any of the 5 feedback forms, it should populate the Main Workbook.

Can this be done without VBA?

Any help or direction would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: When working with files in onedrive, embed them to use it with `Power Query`